# how to transfer tab state of Google Chrome from one install to another without sync

Tags: google-chrome

I reviewed the post here [How to easily transfer tabs from one PC to another?](https://superuser.com/questions/1186523/how-to-easily-transfer-tabs-from-one-pc-to-another) but found that syncing doesn't work too well and I was wondering how I can transfer tabs from one pc/mac/linux to another from a session by copying and pasting files/cache

Comment: What do you mean when you say "from a session"? Moving Chrome profiles is simple, but a specific session may be more difficult if that is what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the default folder from oldsystem (or profile) to new.

Typically @ c:\users\johnny's_profile\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\

It's the folder called "Default"

That's all your bookmarks, etc.  You can/should tell it to ignore duplicate files while copying.

Always backup before making any changes - in case you experience corruption.