# Is it possible to open all Chrome windows and tabs from another computer?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, sync, browser-tabs

I have about 10 windows of Chrome open with a total of about 80 tabs. I'm going to buy a new computer, and I want to open all the windows with the same tabs on the new computer. Is it possible to do it and how? I can sync Chrome to my Google account and then sync it again from the new computer, but how do I open again all windows and tabs?

Comment: with 80 tabs open, I sure hope your new machine has a LOT of RAM.. and multiple cores.  Have you ever looked at the memory footprint for doing this?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1186523/how-to-easily-transfer-tabs-from-one-pc-to-another

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Make sure sync is enabled on both devices.

On your new device, open chrome and open the history (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> on windows).  On the left-side there is an option for **Tabs from other devices** and clicking on it should shows your old device and a list of all the tabs open on it.

In the history view find your old device and click the three-dots button that is on the right-side of the header bar.  There will be an option there to *Open all*.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it.

Comment: It worked, but it logged me out from all websites except Google. Isn't it possible to sync also cookies?

Comment: Hi. Actually I had to use it again - I wanted to delete a profile and accidentally I deleted the wrong profile, but it was synced. I created it again, logged in and then I opened "all tabs from other device" (which is the same device) and I restored all of them with one click.

Comment: Seems broken on current 112.0.5615.49 (Official Build) (arm64)
The first window and its tabs will open, but all other windows remain unopened. sad face.

Comment: Worked for me - but I had to restart chrome on both devices first.
What is sad that currently it doesn't open the tab groups - even if the feature flag for syncing saved groups is on and works ...

Comment: 121.0.6167.140 here, all windows and tabs successfully sync; cookies aren't synced, most likely by design so that's okay; but tab groups are still not synced as the previous commenter notes.