# How can I open a whole Chrome tab group on another machine?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

With Chrome syncing enabled I am able to open individual tabs from other computers, as described in this question: [Is it possible to open all Chrome windows and tabs from another computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1596227/is-it-possible-to-open-all-chrome-windows-and-tabs-from-another-computer)

And it's pretty easy to open all the tabs from another computer. This is pretty quick, but it doesn't preserve the groups at all: [Is it possible to open all Chrome windows and tabs from another computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1596227/is-it-possible-to-open-all-chrome-windows-and-tabs-from-another-computer)

But I want to open a whole group of tabs from that other computer without having to open each tab individually and recreate and rename the group.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I get the impression the Chrome team hasn't made that possible yet. Was looking for the same a while ago, syncing hundreds of Android tabs to Windows. But I'm hoping someone knows a workaround.