# How do I open whole Chrome tab group on another machine?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs

Is there anyone able to move tab groups as is from one Chrome to another?

I did follow this URL: [How can I open a whole Chrome tab group on another machine?](https://superuser.com/q/1719607/1883072) but no solution.

Comment: Why don’t you just move the entire profile?

Answer (score 0):

From the Chrome post
[How do I transfer open tabs to a new device?](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/166378645/how-do-i-transfer-open-tabs-to-a-new-device?hl=en) :

> Another way to transfer open tabs is to use the export/import feature
> in Chrome.
>
> To do this:
>
> 1. Go to the Chrome menu and select "Bookmarks -> Bookmark manager."
> 2. Then, click the menu icon (three dots) in the top-right corner and select "Export bookmarks."
>
> *This will save your bookmarks as a HTML file.*
>
> 3. Then, on your new device, go to the Chrome menu and select "Bookmarks -> Bookmark manager."
> 4. Click the menu icon again and select "Import bookmarks."
> 5. Choose the HTML file you exported from your other device.
>
> You can also use a third-party extension to transfer open tabs. One
> option is Xmarks, which is available for free at
> https://www.xmarks.com/.

If the tab group is not found in your bookmarks, try the method
under "Save your tab group" in the article
[How to create and save Chrome tab groups](https://www.theverge.com/23384844/chrome-google-tab-groups-create-save-how-to).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use [Workona](https://workona.com/) or similar extension. It's very quick in comparison to e.g. bookmarking back and forth.

After you sign up/log in in the 1st tab with the logo icon: [image: Workona logo icon], it automatically syncs all your tabs and shows them as unsaved sessions:

[image: Unsaved sessions]

You can then click one and use **Save** button in top right corner to save them as a workspace that's linked to your account and available on all devices:

[image: Save button]

Once you save, you can continue to work on the workspace and it'll be continuously synced. The free version supports creating up to 5 workspaces with any number of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

How I tend to work is:

1. Sync Chrome Proifle with Gmail Account
2. Bookmark All Group Tabs into 1 Folder and have it visible on the Bookmarks Bar.
3. Move to a new computer.
4. Ensure you're logged into the same account on Chrome and synced.
5. Right-click on the Bookmark Folder you want on the Bookmark tab that you saved earlier and Press Open All.

If you don't want to sync to your Google Profile is to create the Bookmark Folder and copy the while Chrome Profile from Appdata on Windows or Library on MacOS and restore it to same destination on the new device. Tends to copy over almost everything.

Alternatively, you can do what @harrymc has suggested.